# Subquery with "any"instead of all

Tags: php, mysql

There is a search function where you can put the phone number and it will search in all numbers in the database.

And because I want to search in all numbers fields like mobile phone and home phone I made this code:

```
'query_type' => 'default',
    'db_field' => 
    array (
      0 => 'phone_mobile',
      1 => 'phone_work',
      2 => 'phone_other',
      3 => 'phone_fax',
      4 => 'phone_home',
    ),
```

**My problem is:** Sometimes the phone numbers will not include country code for example If you search on this number: 0547896564 it will not show up in the result because the number was stored with country code like this: 0096655454445 or like this +96655454445

**So to solve this:** I'm trying to make the search work from the right to left, like for example: This number 0096655454445 if you want to search on it you can wright 454445 the last 6 numbers and it will be in the result.

**How I can make the search working by searching on any combined numbers instead of the whole phone number?**

I searched around and I found that I need something called Subquery
So my code will look like this:

```
 'phone' => 
  array (
    'query_type' => 'format',
  'operator' => 'subquery',
'subquery' => "I don't really know what exactly should I write here"
  'db_field' => 
    array (
      0 => 'phone_mobile',
      1 => 'phone_work',
      2 => 'phone_other',
      3 => 'phone_fax',
      4 => 'phone_home',
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: *I want to search on numbers by typing any combined numbers like for example this number 006547899844 I can search for it by just typing 4789 or 99844 or 654* There is no (easy) way for to improve the searching for a substring in the string. `WHERE column LIKE CONCAT('%', criteria, '%')` cannot use index. Only when the criteria is the prefix or the postfix of the value you can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the specific problem of the search string matching patterns within a string the simplest solution is the use the SQL search LIKE, so an example for the phone_mobile field would be:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE mobile_phone LIKE ?;
```

The parameter for the where clause should be of the form %textNumber% (e.g. %3743%). Here the % act as wild card for the search.

Looking beyond your problem to search across multiple fields, I would personally run the sql statement for each field and populate an array of results.

[MySQL Doc Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest trying OR combined with LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE (phone_mobile LIKE '% $number %' OR phone_work LIKE '% $number %' OR phone_other LIKE '% $number %' OR phone_fax LIKE '% %number %' OR phone_home LIKE '% $number %')
```